# How to swap array elements and variables effectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jQuery function to swap images inside of a grid I have made. The only problem is that the variable returns the string with "url()" which causes an error. I would like to be able to swap the images properly so as to avoid having the same image appear in the grid twice.

Code:

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  var imgArray = ["../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/j.png", "../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/k.png", "../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/l.png"]
  var imgSelect = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  if (number == 1) {
    var imgChange = "one";
  } else if (number == 2) {
    var imgChange = "two";
  } else if (number == 3) {
    var imgChange = "three";
  } else if (number == 4) {
    var imgChange = "four";
  } else if (number == 5) {
    var imgChange = "five";
  } else if (number == 6) {
    var imgChange = "six";
  } else if (number == 7) {
    var imgChange = "seven";
  } else if (number == 8) {
    var imgChange = "eight";
  } else {
    var imgChange = "nine";
  }
  var temp = $("." + imgChange).css("background-image");
  $("." + imgChange).css("background-image", "url(" + imgArray[imgSelect] + ")");
  imgArray.splice(imgSelect, 1, temp);
  alert(imgArray);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="stats__grid--desktop">
  <div class="grid__top">
    <div class="grid__top--item one" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/a.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item two" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/b.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item three" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/c.png);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__mid">
    <div class="grid__top--item four" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/d.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item five" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/e.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item six" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/f.png);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__bottom">
    <div class="grid__top--item seven" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/g.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item eight" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/h.png);"></div>
    <div class="grid__top--item nine" style="background-image: url(../css/images/work-template/bench/stats2/i.png);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this a problem? When you set the CSS, the browser resolves the relative URL into an absolute URL. But they're both equivalent, so it doesn't matter which one you put into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get string value from a map / object

```
var data = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six',7: 'seven', 8: 'eight',9: 'nine'}
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
var imgChange = data[number];
```

Comment: His problem isn't getting the elements out of the array. His problem is that when he does `var temp = $("." + imgChange).css("background-image");` it returns the full URL, not the relative path like the original array elements.